# react-native ViewPagerAndroid peek property

Tags: android, react-native, view, pager, peek

How to properly use the "peekEnabled" property on ViewPagerAndroid ?

```
<ViewPagerAndroid peekEnabled={true} >{this.props.children}</ViewPagerAndroid>
```

**I want something like this**

[image]

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Not yet, using carousel

Comment: Darn, please let me know if you solve it ever. I will let you know if I solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `peekEnabled` to work as expected needs `ViewPagerAndroid` to have `padding`.
Looking at the [RN source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/70a3ececc368a8d0fe4b57b13ac956ad99a637c7/Libraries/Components/ViewPager/ViewPagerAndroid.android.js#L158), child views style is set to `position: absolute` and `right,left,top,bottom: 0` so the parent's container padding has no effect.

As a workaround you can set `pageMargin` to a negative value and use `paddingLeft,paddindRight` in the child views to achieve the same effect.

e.g:

```
<ViewPagerAndroid pageMargin={-70} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ padding: 35 }}>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink', flex: 1 }} />
  </View>
  <View style={{ padding: 35 }}>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'cyan', flex: 1 }} />
  </View>
  <View style={{ padding: 35 }}>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'magenta', flex: 1 }} />
  </View>
</ViewPagerAndroid>
```

[demo](https://snack.expo.dev/h6_HxqZTIm)

Comment: Dang that is interesting. Seems like a workaround for a bug. Thanks for sharing such tips! I would never have found thsi out! How much padding? Even just 1dpi padding? May you please link the source code you mention. If possible may you please share your own example code.

Comment: @Noitidart I think the values would vary, I found [this](http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/android-viewpager-cards-1) helpful. I added a link to a working snack to demonstrate.